# Retrieve DataExtension DataRetentionPeriod Month and Week swapped?

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap

In my DataExtension I have the following settings:
[image]

If I do a retrieve on the DataExtension and look for the DataRetentionPeriod, it is set to "Week" instead of "Months".

When switching the settings inside the DataExtension to 1 Week, the retrieve adds DataRetentionPeriod: "Months".

This seems to be a bug / wrong allocation on SFMC end. Or am I doing somethings wrong here?

Using a simple WSProxy script:

```
<script runat=server>
    Platform.Load("Core", "1.1.5");

    try{

        var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();

        req = prox.retrieve("DataExtension", ['DataRetentionPeriod'], { 
            Property: "Name", 
            SimpleOperator: "equals", 
            Value: 'TestDEWithRetention' 
        });
        Write(Stringify(req.Results[0].DataRetentionPeriod));

    } catch(e){
        Write(Stringify(e));
    }

</script>
```

Comment: About a year ago I noticed the same and kept a note: DataRetentionPeriod - days / weeks / months / years; API Options: Days, Weeks*, Months**, Years
*Bug: When specifying "Weeks", the UI result is "Months"
**Bug: When specifying "Months", the UI result is "Weeks"

This was when _creating_ data extensions, so it seems to be relating to the dataExtension object, not to your method (retrieve). So I'd say yes, it's a bug. Definitely something that has been around for a while.

Comment: yeah, it looks like a mismatch on their labels they output into the object. The ids associated with it are correct - which is what the system uses. It really should be an easy issue to solve, but I doubt it will be high enough priority for SFMC to add it into any releases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For everyone who come across this issue, here is the bug ticket lodged last year (2019).

The important takeaway is this:

***The duration is correctly listed on the UI on the Data Extension properties section when clicking the Manage Policies button.***

---

[Bug ticket](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?title=soap-api-data-extension-retrieve-request-returns-weeks-instead-of-months-for-dataretentionperiod-property-value&Id=a1p3A000001GKYw)

### SOAP API Data Extension retrieve request returns Weeks instead of Months for DataRetentionPeriod property value

> *Last updated 2019-12-10 ·Reference W-7000178 ·Reported By 2 users*
>
> Summary
>       When the properties of a Data Extension are retrieved via SOAP API, the DataRetentionPeriod in the API response shows Weeks instead of Months and Months instead of Weeks.
>
> Repro
>       The following outline creation of Data Extension with Retention Policy using Months duration via Email Studio and the retrieval of the Data Extension properties via SOAP API. The same issue occurs when creating Data Extension via Contact Builder:
>
> - In Email Studio > Subscribers > Data Extensions, click Create.
> - Select Standard Data Extension. Then click OK.
> - Give DE the Name 'DataRetentionMonths' and External Key 'DataRetentionMonths'. Click Next.
> - In Data Retention Policy, toggle Retention Setting to On. Select 'All Records' under Delete and set Period to After 6 Months. Click Next.
> - Add a field to the DE and click Create.
>
> Note: Data Extension is created in UI and has the value Months for retention duration when reviewed by clicking into the DE properties and selecting the Manage Policies button.
>
> - Perform a SOAP API retrieve request with the following body:

```
<soapenv:Body>
    <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">;
        <RetrieveRequest>
            <ObjectType>DataExtension</ObjectType>
            <Properties>Name</Properties>
            <Properties>CustomerKey</Properties>
            <Properties>ObjectID</Properties>
            <Properties>CategoryId</Properties>
            <Properties>Client.ID</Properties>
            <Properties>DataRetentionPeriod</Properties>
            <Properties>DataRetentionPeriodLength</Properties>
            <Properties>DataRetentionPeriodUnitOfMeasure</Properties>
            <Properties>DeleteAtEndOfRetentionPeriod</Properties>
            <Properties>ResetRetentionPeriodOnImport</Properties>
            <Properties>RetainUntil</Properties>
            <Properties>RowBasedRetention</Properties>
            <Properties>Status</Properties>
            <Filter xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
                <Property>CustomerKey</Property>
                <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
                <Value>DataRetentionMonths</Value> -- external key
            </Filter>
        </RetrieveRequest>
    </RetrieveRequestMsg>
</soapenv:Body>
```

> The resulting response shows Weeks for DataRetentionPeriod, as per the following example:

```
<Results xsi:type="DataExtension">
    <Client>
        <ID>0000000</ID>
    </Client>
    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
    <PartnerProperties>
        <Name>CategoryId</Name>
        <Value>0000000</Value>
    </PartnerProperties>
    <ObjectID>44cd3ebc-6a1a-ea11-0000-1402ec94ecf1</ObjectID>
    <CustomerKey>DataRetentionMonths</CustomerKey>
    <Name>DataRetentionMonths</Name>
    <DataRetentionPeriodLength>6</DataRetentionPeriodLength>
    <DataRetentionPeriodUnitOfMeasure>5</DataRetentionPeriodUnitOfMeasure>
    <RowBasedRetention>false</RowBasedRetention>
    <ResetRetentionPeriodOnImport>false</ResetRetentionPeriodOnImport>
    <DeleteAtEndOfRetentionPeriod>true</DeleteAtEndOfRetentionPeriod>
    <RetainUntil>6/9/2020 12:00:00 AM</RetainUntil>
    <DataRetentionPeriod>Weeks</DataRetentionPeriod>
    <Status>None</Status>
</Results>
```

> Note: 
>   the same issue is observed for a Data Extension with the Weeks duration selected on UI. The API will instead return Months. No issue observed with the duration Days or Years.
>
> Workaround:
>   **There is no workaround currently to get the API to correctly return the DataRetentionPeriod when the retention settings use Weeks or Months duration**. The duration is correctly listed on the UI on the Data Extension properties section when clicking the Manage Policies button.

Comment: As a note, the issue is on the translation to the retention 'label' from the numeric code id. The code is correct on the back end, which is why it is correctly labeled on the UI. The numeric code (which you can see if you look at the network tab of dev tools) is an integer that represents the time period. The output locations (UI, SOAP Object, etc.) then translate this to an easier to understand label. When implemented the SOAP Object translator was incorrect - but it has not been of high enough priority for a fix. I doubt it ever will, with SOAP likely going away in future.

Comment: But this would still apply to WSProxy which I assume will stuck for a bit longer.

Comment: WSProxy IS SOAP API.

Comment: hmmm - I thought WSProxy is a proxy between the Marketing Cloud SOAP Web Service and SSJS itself. When you said SOAP will be going away in the future I thought just the web access not the layer itself. Are you saying WSProxy will go away in the near future or will be replaced?

Comment: I am saying that currently the SOAP API is the only thing WSProxy is connected to. If they adjust this to include REST (which I hear whispers of) then it will not be going anywhere. And although I say 'going away in the future' in SFMC time, that could be 5-10 years (look how long it took to retire XML API). I added that in as I believe all efforts on API are now on REST only and SOAP is more of a maintain status quo situation until it is able to be sunset.

Comment: The label part I mention has nothing to do with whether you get it from WSProxy or from an API call via POSTman, the incorrect match happens at the object level - which is why I stated 'WSproxy is SOAP API'. because the return on that is identical since it gathers the info from the same SOAP Object.

Comment: thanks for the clarification